# byte value larger than 127

Tags: java, byte

//Ok makes sense

```
Byte b = (byte)207;
System.out.println(b); //value = 207
```

//ok doesn't make sense

```
Integer x = Integer.parseInt("11001111", 2); //207
Byte sens = (byte)x.intValue(); //207
System.out.println(sens); //Value = -49
System.out.println(sens.intValue()); //Value = -49
```

Whats going on here?

**How do I declare/represent an 8 bit byte with a value higher than 127 then**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

bytes in Java are signed, so they go from -128 to 127.  Casting an int like that will pick up the high bit at 1 (indicating a negative number in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) signed numbers) and convert it to the negative number -49.

From there, when you convert it back to an integer with `sens.intValue()`, it picks up the new negative value and returns it, so you still get -49.

You will need to store bytes larger than 128 in an `int` datatype, unfortunately.

Comment: This does not explain why the first case prints 207

Comment: they first case doesn't print 207, he just has a comment of 207 next to it.  the value of `x.intValue()` is 207, but the cast to byte will turn it into -49

Comment: `System.out.println((byte)x.intValue());` will print -49.  `System.out.println(x.intValue());` will print 207

Comment: Answer is correct, but just tossing this out there for future reads: storing the value in a `short` datatype might be more appropriate than `int`. (Short is 2 bytes, whereas int is 4 bytes. Coming from a byte value, a short should be sufficient and it will save 2 bytes of memory, which is minor, but can accumulate when you have a lot of byte values like this.)

Answer (score 1):

Since Java's Byte is signed you **can't** represent value larger than 127 in byte.

In Your example:

```
Byte b = (byte)207;
System.out.println(b); //value = 207
```

There is an error. Output of println is -49.

```
Byte b = (byte)207;
System.out.println(b); //value = -49
```

Which means that both cases are identical.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it can't go over 127 positive, but it can go 128 negative, is that the first 1 out of the 8 digits in a byte represents if it is a negative number or positive:

1 = negative

0 = positive

and since you can use "1111 1111" for negative numbers, you can get -127.

Answer (score 0):

255 + the negative byteValue + 1 returns your number with the counter operation. Still recommend storage in a int.

If you like it bitwise, better put a numeric ring around it.